# Projection transformation matrix problem.

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a 3-Dimensional position vector that can be described by some $X,Y$, and $Z$ coordinate. And I want to project this vector onto a 2D plane, that can be described by some $a$ and $b$ coordinate, with the projection transformation:

$a = X/(X+Y+Z)$

$b = Y/(X+Y+Z)$

Is there some transformation matrix that could perform this projection? Would this be a linear transformation?

I'm trying to find what the transformation matrix is, but I'm getting tripped up. I imagine since our input is a 3-tuple vector (3x1), and our output is a 2-tuple vector (2x1), then the transformation matrix must be 2x3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I find your question confusing. If you want to map $(x,y,z)\to(\frac{x}{x+y+z},\frac{y}{x+y+z})$ the transformation will be nonlinear.

Comment: As @ColeG97 said, the fact that you have a reciprocal automatically makes it nonlinear?

Comment: I figured it was nonlinear, just wanted to confirm. Also confirmed it by seeing if T(a+b) = T(a) + T(b) and found that to not be true, which proves it's not linear.

I'm still learning linear algebra, which generally only deals with linear transformations. But one question I have, is just because this transformation is nonlinear, that doesn't prevent a nonlinear projection transformation matrix from existing, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Computer graphics usually works with projective geometry. Here's a $3\times 3$ matrix that will encode your projection:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
You interpret it as mapping from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$ by sending $\vec v = \begin{bmatrix} X\\Y\\Z\end{bmatrix}$ to $A\vec v\in\Bbb R^3$ and then "dehomogenizing" by mapping
$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} x_1/x_3 \\ x_2/x_3 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \leftrightsquigarrow \begin{bmatrix} x_1/x_3 \\ x_2/x_3 \end{bmatrix}\in\Bbb R^2.$$

There are lots of sources on the linear algebra in computer graphics, but, for some reason, my personal favorite is Section 2 of Chapter 7 of *Linear Algebra: A Geometric Approach*, by Theodore Shifrin and Malcolm R. Adams.